# Copy global char** in a new char**

Tags: c, arrays, string, malloc, strcpy

```
char * seleccion[5]={"  ","  ","  ","  "," "};

char **armar_Equipazo() {
  char** equipo= (char **)malloc(sizeof(seleccion));
  for(int i =0 ; i<5 ; i++)
      strcpy(equipo[i],seleccion[i]);
  return equipo;
}
```

I need copy a char ** in a new "array", but my code do not succed because my malloc is wrong buy I do not know why. 
Can you help me please ?

Comment: `strcpy(equipo[i],seleccion[i]);` --> `equipo[i] = seleccion[i];` or `equipo[i] = strdup(seleccion[i]);`

Comment: Because you allocate memory only for pointers to strings, but didn't for strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you are going to copy. If you want to copy the elements of the 
array `seleccion` in a new array then you can write

```
char * seleccion[5] = { "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", " " };

char ** armar_Equipazo() 
{
    char **equipo = ( char **)malloc( sizeof( seleccion ) );

    memcpy( equipo, seleccion, sizeof( seleccion ) );

    return equipo;
}
```

If you want to make copies of the strings pointed to by the elements of the array `seleccion` then you should write

```
char * seleccion[5] = { "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", " " };

char ** armar_Equipazo() 
{
    char **equipo = ( char **)malloc( sizeof( seleccion ) );

    for( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( seleccion  / sizeof( *seleccion ); i++ )
    {
        equipo[i]  = malloc( strlen( seleccion[i] ) + 1 );
        strcpy( equipo[i], seleccion[i] );
    }

    return equipo;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you.I need the second.